# Sum vector data correlating with a second vector layer

Tags: qgis

There are a lot of questions *very* similar to mine, but I couldn't find one that accurately described what I want to do.  I am working in QGIS.

I have one vector layer which, among other attributes, has a production volume for oil wells.   I have a second layer which represents townships.  Some townships have five wells, some have none etc., all with different levels of production.

I want to create a new layer which displays all the townships with a summation of the total production volume within the township.  Can anyone think of an efficient way to do this? EDIT: I would also like to be able to the sum of the production volumes to the township layer.

Thanks!

Comment: Are these layers represented by points? Polygons?

Comment: They are both polygons.

Comment: Yes, there are many that are similar *and* answer your question.  You can find some of them with a site search on, say, [point polygon summary qgis](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=point+polygon+summary+qgis). I have indicated a particular one of these questions as a duplicate because it appears to have a clear, thorough, and correct answer that covers your case (unlike some of the others, unfortunately).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I saw this, but I don't think these actually are the same case.  

Please correct me if I'm wrong, however this question appears to be about counting the number of points (and corresponding attributes) within a buffer.  I would like to sum a value from the attribute tables of one vector layer and make that value a new column in a second polygon layer.

To clarify, the new column would ideally be the sum of all the production volumes of all the wells within a township.

If you think the above still answers my question, please advise.

Comment: Does your wells dataset contain the polygons that fall exclusively within one township? If not you would need to decide on strategy for cases when one well polygon overlaps different townships.

Comment: They do fall into one township exclusively, however the borders do touch.  I know exactly how I want to partition the data, I just can't figure out how to do it.